# Magnolia prevent creating child page with parent page template

Tags: jcr, magnolia

In magnolia, My site hierarchy as follows

```
Page 1
  Page 1.1
     Page 1.1.1
  Page 1.2
Page 2
 Page 2.1
Page 3
```

etc..

But I am also able to create Page template 1.1 under Page 1.1, how can I prevent this ?

I read category and availability and all, but this is not helping?

Any help

Answer (score 1):

Categories are actually the thing you're looking for:

For your setup, you could create three page templates:

- `MyHome` of category `home`
- `MySection` of category `section`
- `MyArticle` of category `article`

Of course `Page 1` should use template `MyHome`, `Page 1.1` should use `MySection` and `Page 1.1.1` therefore `MyArticle`.

Doc about categories: http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS45/Template+definitions#Templatedefinitions-Categoriesandsubcategories

As far as I know, availability can only controlled globally and not for sub-trees or levels (at least in Magnolia CE).

Comment: Thanks for reply, but under section category, magnolia will list all articles, while I want only certain articles for certain section type. And this can be achieved by writing custom TemplateAvailability class by overriding isAvailable() method.